# Changing a sound effect Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

I have about 25 similar sound files, each with a different frequency. I've written some code to change which sound file is playing based on a speed variable that changes. In theory the pitch of the sound should increase with speed (The higher the file number the higher the pitch.) Here's what I've written:

```
CurrentSound = 'CarEngine0.wav'
OldSound = CurrentSound

while True:

    CurrentSound = 'CarEngine' + str(abs(int(speed*2))) + '.wav'
    CarSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(CurrentSound)
    if not OldSound == CurrentSound:
        OldSound = CurrentSound
        CarSound.stop()
    CarSound.play(-1)
```

If I call the `CurrentSound` and `OldSound` varibles to print, they do change, but the sound doesn't seem to. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, You have 25 sound files and you want to play them in the increasing order of speed variable. The 25 sound files-names are sequenced according to their pitch.

### Setup

The solution assumes you have your audio files in a folder and they list in the increasing order of their pitch in sequence.

The code will load files listed  sequentially in an folder based on speed counter [ that you can modify as per your needs ]

The code was written on windows 8 and python 2.7

### Sample Code

```
import pygame.mixer, pygame.time
import os

mixer = pygame.mixer  
mixer.init()  #Initialize Mixer

#Your path to audio files
filepath = "C:\\yourAudioFilePath\\"

#Iterate through counter and  audio files

for x, i in zip(range(0,25),os.listdir(filepath)):
    if i.endswith(".wav"):
        mySoundFile = mixer.Sound(filepath + i)
        print "Speed Variable = " , x , " and file = ", i 
        channel = mySoundFile.play(0)
        while channel.get_busy():  #Check if Channel is busy
            pygame.time.wait(100)  #  wait in ms until song is played
        print "........"
```

### Output

I renamed bunch of audio files sequentially to match your requirements.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Speed Variable =  0  playing file =  audio000.wav
........
Speed Variable =  1  playing file =  audio001.wav
........
Speed Variable =  2  playing file =  audio002.wav
........
Speed Variable =  3  playing file =  audio003.wav
........
Speed Variable =  5  playing file =  audio005.wav
........
Speed Variable =  6  playing file =  audio006.wav
........
Speed Variable =  7  playing file =  audio007.wav
........
Speed Variable =  8  playing file =  audio008.wav
........
Speed Variable =  9  playing file =  audio009.wav
........
Speed Variable =  10  playing file =  audio0010.wav
........
Speed Variable =  11  playing file =  audio0011.wav
........
Speed Variable =  12  playing file =  audio0012.wav
........
Speed Variable =  13  playing file =  audio0013.wav
........
Speed Variable =  14  playing file =  audio0014.wav
........
Speed Variable =  15  playing file =  audio0015.wav
........
Speed Variable =  16  playing file =  audio0016.wav
........
Speed Variable =  17  playing file =  audio0017.wav
........
Speed Variable =  18  playing file =  audio0018.wav
........
Speed Variable =  19  playing file =  audio0019.wav
........
Speed Variable =  20  playing file =  audio0020.wav
........
Speed Variable =  21  playing file =  audio0021.wav
........
Speed Variable =  22  playing file =  audio0022.wav
........
Speed Variable =  23  playing file =  audio0023.wav
........
Speed Variable =  24  playing file =  audio0024.wav
........
>>>
```